# For any square-free $n \geq 1$ and $a \in \Bbb{Z}/n$ including $\gcd(a,n) \neq 1$, then in the list $a, a^2, a^3, \dots$ either $a$ or $a^2$ repeats?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic, conjectures

For example, modulo $30$ we have that $\gcd(5, 30) = 5$, but $5, 5^2, 5^3 = 5, 5^2, \dots$ goes the list, so both repeat.

We know it's true when $\gcd(a,n) = 1$ because a cyclic group is formed in $\Bbb{Z}/n^{\times}$, s it's sufficient to prove the case when $\gcd(a, n) = d \neq 1$.

Another example:

$$
n = 15:\\
3, 3^2, 3^3=-3,-3^2,(-3)^2=3^2, \dots \\
6,6,6, \dots \\
9,9^2=6,9, \dots\\
5,10,5,10, \dots\\
$$

Is this hopelessly difficult to prove?

Comment: If $a$ repeats then $a^2$ repeats, so we can just focus on that.

Comment: $a$ always repeats. See Carmichael’s theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function#Exponential_cycle_length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Chinese Remainder theorem, $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a product of $\mathbb{Z}_{p_i}$ for prime $p_i$, and we can view $a$ as an element of $\prod_i \mathbb{Z}_{p_i}$, $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_k)$. For any of the component rings, $\mathbb{Z}_{p_i}$, we have that the sequence $a_i^m$ must repeat either with period $1$ (if $a_i = 0$) or with period dividing $p_i-1$ (otherwise). Take the lcm of the periods of all the $a_i^m$ sequences for all the component rings and you'll get the period for the product ring. So $a^m$ always repeats.

Comment: @DanielDonnelly I'm not sure what you mean. I'm using $m$ as the variable that makes it a sequence. I.e. $a^m$ denotes $a,a^2,a^3,\dots$

Comment: Are we 100% sure that any $a \in \Bbb{Z}/p_n\#$ will do?  I.e. that its power sequence always loops back to $a$?  What about if $\gcd(a, p_n\#) \neq 1$?

Comment: @DanielDonnelly $p_i$ is prime (due to square-freeness) so the only possibilities for the gcd are $1$ and $p_i$ these correspond to $a_i$ being in $\mathbb{Z}_{p_i}^{\times}$ (with period (dividing $p_i-1$)) and $a_i$ being $0$ (with period 1) respectively.